# Angular 7 Unable to resolve spring boot rest API hostname

Tags: angular, jboss, jboss7.x

I have bundled an Angular7 app as static content within a spring boot REST API into a .war archive and deployed it on JBoss EAP 7.3. The application deploys successfully and I am able to see the login page. However, when I try to login, I get a `net::err_name_not_resolved` error in my browser console and when I check the network tab, I see that the hostname is omitted whilst angular is trying to call the REST API for authentication, hence the error reported in the console. In my angular configs, I have defined `apiHost='/'` and expect that this would be resolved to the machine's host or IP at runtime, but this is not working. I have also created a jboss-web.xml where I defined the context root as `/`.

I would greatly appreciate any help in this regard.

**EDIT**

I need this to work because I am deploying the .war file in a JBoss cluster, hence, the application should be reachable from any of the cluster members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolved the issue by using `apiHost='.'`

I can now call up my application using any of the hosts participating in the JBoss cluster.

Answer (score 0):

> In my angular configs, I have defined apiHost='/' and expect that this
> would be resolved to the machine's host or IP at runtime

You have just loaded some static files (html, js) in your server that spring boot run. Those static files (representing the frontend) are then served to the client. The client can be anyone.

So if server runs on ip 192.168.1.1 the client can have the same or a completely different IP. Therefore you must provide that info.

Think of it in a simple way. Those html and js files are handled only by your browser which doesn't know anything about the spring boot server. Somehow the call that is invoked in those html, js files must specify where the server is.

Therefore your `apiHost='/'` is wrong. It could be `apiHost='localhost'` or `apiHost='some Specific Ip'`

Comment: Yes, you're right, the challenge is that I am deploying the application to a JBoss cluster and need that whatever host (cluster member) on which the app is being launched is resolved by angular.